# How to handle the `key' argument in PyObject_GetItem() function

Tags: python, c, python-c-extension

I am writing a `python` module from a c library of my own, I need to know how to handle the [`PyObject_GetItem()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetItem) function, specifically the `key` argument, the documentation is not very helpful and I have seen an example where the solution is

```
Py_hash_t hash;

hash = PyObject_Hash(key);
```

but the problem is, that I would like to be able to know whether `key` is a string or an integer.

I could use the `PyObject_Hash()` methdod if there is a way to differentitate a string key from an integer key since I can also compute the hash value corresponding to the string using the Python hash function, but i'd rather not do that because I already have a binary search implemented on the list that I am trying to be able to access via subscripting in python.

I also tried

```
PyArg_ParseTuple(key, "i", ...);
```

and for the string to check which one succeeds, but then the interpreter throws an exception because the `key` is not a tuple.

Comment: Why do you need to know the type? What if it's neither?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because I want to provide two methods to fetch the elements, one by index and by element name, there is a name associated with each one, and it's really important to use it to be able to access the element.

Comment: How would you do it in Python? Look for appropriate C-api equivalents to the Python tools you would use.

Comment: @user2357112 I have no idea because i have limited python knowledge. That's why I am asking, and that's why initially I didn't add the [c](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c) tag to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the way to do it properly, there is a [`PyUnicode_Check()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html) macro that takes a single `PyObject` parameter and returns `0` if the object is not a `unicode` object, so it returns `0` for the `int` key, and non-zero for the string key.

That was exactly what I needed since now I can proceed to extract the text and perform a binary search in my list.

Also, there is a [`PyObject_TypeCheck()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html) function which returns the type of an object, very useful in this case too.